# How do i run Selenium(javascript) in Chrome extension development?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

Developing a chrome extension where I collect information about the same product on different shopping sites. I am getting the price and name information of a product on Amazon, I want to learn the price information on other sites using Selenium.

```
const addProductImageTest = () =>{  
  const newProduct = {
  productImage : document.getElementById("landingImage").src,
  productPrice : document.getElementsByClassName("a-price aok-align-center")[0].children[0].innerText,
  productAvailability : document.getElementById("availability").children[0].innerText,
  productName : document.getElementById("productTitle").innerText,   
  };
    chrome.storage.sync.set({
    [product]: JSON.stringify([...allProducts, newProduct])
  });
 }
```

The code above is the button click event that I use to get the data of the product on Amazon in contentScript.js.

```
const {By,Key,Builder,WebElement,JavascriptExecutor} = require("selenium-webdriver");
require("chromedriver");
const sleep = ms => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms));

async function test_case_amazon(){  
    let chromeDriver = await new Builder().forBrowser("chrome").build();

    await chromeDriver.get("https://amazon.com.tr");
        await sleep(1000);
    await chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='field-keywords']")).sendKeys("Corsair iCUE 4000X RGB", Key.RETURN);
        await sleep(2000);
    await chromeDriver.findElement(By.id("sp-cc-rejectall-link")).click();
        await sleep(2000);
    await chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@data-component-type='s-search-result']")).click();
 let ege = chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class ='a-price aok-align-center']/span")).getAttribute('innerText');

    await sleep(4000);       
    console.log(ege);
}
test_case_amazon();
```

This code is the part where I get the product's data with Selenium. I want to use the Selenium code part in contentScript.js for different shopping sites, but I don't know how to change the manifest.json file and import Selenium. Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Are you saying you want to ***test*** your extension using Selenium, or are you expecting to somehow embed Selenium within the extension itself? Because the latter isn't going to work

Comment: I plan to embed Selenium inside the extension. How else can I obtain data without going to other sites? Is there a way you can suggest?

Comment: Sure, use JS to get the data from the DOM as you normally would. No need for Selenium at all.

Comment: Can you show me an article or link where I can learn to do this?

Comment: recommend chrome's cdp

Comment: You can't because extensions are client-side javascript only.